# Formulário de múltiplos passos, perdendo valores das variáveis quando muda de página

Tags: php, html, mysql

Temos três páginas PHP com formulário html.
Na primeira pagina temos os campos mostrando os valores das variáveis e os campos hidden contendo os valores das variáveis assim:

```
<input name="nome" type="hidden" value=".$nome." >
```

Da primeira página para a segunda, todos os valores são passados corretamente via `$_POST['nome']` dessa forma, pois chequei com `echo var_dump($nome)`.
Da segunda pagina para a terceira que é o processamento do formulário preenchido cujos valores dos campos hidden vão para o banco de dados, os valores dessas variáveis se perdem.
O `var_dump()` mostra que as variáveis ficaram nulas (`NULL`) e também recebo a mensagem:

> Indefined index [...]

Nota-se que as variáveis que só existem na segunda página são inseridas no banco normalmente.

Se eu passar diretamente sem campo `hidden`, vai pro banco de dados o valor `.$nome.`

O que eu poderia estar fazendo de errado? De que outra forma poderia avançar com essas variáveis até a terceira pagina?

Comment: Olha amigo essa pratica que você esta usando de devolver as variáveis ao frontend e re-assimilar para as próximas páginas é muito insegura e falha como você mesmo disse. Eu recomendo você trabalhar com `$_SESSION` do PHP, pode ler mais [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php), armazene apenas uma vez sua variável na sessão e não precisa colocar em campos escondidos pras próximas.

Comment: Uhmm... Então existe essa falha mesmo? Não necessariamente é um erro meu? Ok, Obrigado!

Comment: Não @Vinicius, o que ele quis dizer é que o modo como está fazendo é suscetível a falhas, não necessariamente uma falha ou bug do PHP. Foi provavelmente um erro seu em algum ponto.

Comment: Nota: ``var_dump()`` não necessita de ``echo`` antes dele

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para trabalhar em um formulário com múltiplos passos/telas, é aconselhável que você use as sessões, no PHP você pode utilizar através da variável global [**`$_SESSION`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

Assim você não precisa a cada formulário ficar enviando e recuperando os dados de uma página para outra. Sem contar que você não precisa ficar adicionando registros ao banco em cada página, você pode adicionar todos os registros ao mesmo tempo no último passo, assim fica mais fácil de tratar os dados, facilita a manutenção e o código fica até mais legível.

### Criando sessões:

Você pode definir os dados, assim:

```
$_SESSION['formulario']['nome']  = $_POST['nome']
$_SESSION['formulario']['email'] = $_POST['email']
```

### Recuperando sessões:

Na próxima página você pode recuperar esses dados, fazendo assim:

```
$_SESSION['formulario']['nome']
```

Você pode recuperar os dados em qualquer lugar e em qualquer uma das páginas daqui pra frente. Fica muito mais fácil trabalhar assim. Esqueça ter que colocar o `input` `hidden`, isso não é necessário aqui.

Não esqueça de usar [**`session_start()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) para iniciar a sessão nas páginas que irá utilizar.

Comment: Pensei também na falta de controle que aparenta ser, pois se $_SESSION esta em qualquer lugar, logo podemos ter também formulários muito parecidos com campos de mesmo nome. Pelo seu exemplo podemos então especificar de qual formulário estamos pegando as informações. O que passa mais segurança e menos dúvida  (por exemplo: de onde esta vindo tal valor). Obrigado! Vou passar a usar mais a $_SESSION a partir de agora.

Comment: Sim, durante a execução do seu sistema, você pode adicionar vários tipos de sessões, até mesmo preferências do usuário, trackear a navegação do usuário, onde ele clicou, várias coisas. Não deixe de usar.

Comment: @Ricardo é boa pratica usar $_SESSION mesmo quando temos muitos utilizadores em simultâneo?

Comment: Sim, a sessão é utilizada apenas para o usuário corrente, não é compartilhada com outros usuários.